# How to compress json to get it with `bodyParser.json`

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, compression

I want to send to my server a compressed json.

I prefer to compress the data in browser.([explainer](https://github.com/wicg/compression/blob/master/explainer.md)) and get it to bodyParser.json middleware.

client side function something like this:

```
export function compressGzip(input) {
  const stream = new Response(input).body.pipeThrough(
    new CompressionStream('gzip')
  )
  return new Response(stream)
}
```

my request in react.js:

```
return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: bodyContent
  }).then(res => res.blob())
```

node.js:

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "10mb"
  })
);
```

What is the way to do the compression according to this data and does it make sense?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it with blob, it works perfectly :)

The code:

client side:

```
export function compressGzip(input) {
  const stream = new Response(input).body.pipeThrough(
    new CompressionStream('gzip')
  )
  return new Response(stream).blob()
}

const bodyContent = await compressGzip(JSON.stringify({data: data})

return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: bodyContent
  }).then(res => res.blob())
```

server side - node.js:

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    limit: "10mb"
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with zlib, but not GZIP.

Firstly, I have this client-side function....

```
function compressBody(body) {

    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {

        zlib.deflate(body, (err, buffer) => {
            if(err){
                console.log("Error Zipping");
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log("Zipped");

            resolve(buffer);
        });
     });

}
```

To call function....

```
let compressedBody = await compressBody(JSON.stringify(body));
```

I can then assign this compressedBody var to the webervice call...

```
 var promise = fetch(ServiceUrl, {method: 'POST', headers:headers, body:compressedBody}).then((result) => result.json() );
```

You will then need to change the server-side code to accept a compressed body.  I used Express and did the following...

```
var BodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('body-parser-zlib')(BodyParser);

var app = express();

// Other code....
app.use(BodyParser.zlib()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(BodyParser.json({"inflate": true})); // support json encoded bodies
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't want to change server side. Any idea with gzip?
From docs of body parser, it seems that 'Unicode encoding of the body' supports.[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions)
 thanks again!.

Comment: I had no choice but to alter server side otherwise the API would not know to handle zipped/compressed payloads.  If you simply compress the payload from the client and call your service, you're likely to get a 500 in return.  Sorry, never used GZIP.